# How to return data to Command line Interface from Application (Exe) written on LabVIEW?

Tags: command-line-interface, exe, labview

I've created an application that performs some complex maths operation and return value! The thing is I have a UI but I want to call this application silently from CLI. Can we do this in LabVIEW? I use LabVIEW 2017 Professional Development System. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

I searched on NI Forums! I didn't get any solutions :(

Comment: Do an internet search for "labview command line interface". There are several relevant articles/discussions on the web about this very topic.


FYI: The NI Forum search tool is pretty crappy. Better to use google.

Comment: Ok I’ll try with google then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one useful package on VI Package Manager. It's called [LabVIEW CLI](https://github.com/JamesMc86/LabVIEW-CLI)

User can install this application along with their application and then call the vi or the exe directly!